# Correct way to join core tables in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, resource-model, coding-standards, crud

I am able to join table something like this..

```
$totalsales = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['complete']);   
 $totalsales->join(['item' => 'sales_order_item'], 'main_table.entity_id = item.item_id');
```

But MEQP2 Codesniffer gives following error.

```
 186 | WARNING | Data access method JOIN detected outside of Resource
     |         | Model
```

Please let me know the correct way of doing so.

Comment: Which is `$totalsales` instance?

Comment: its instance of ordercollectionfactory

Comment: The collection works correctly?

Comment: Above code works correctly but i am searching the correct way of doing the functionality

Comment: There's not really anything wrong the code you've shown us (it is context-less, can't comment much further on what else is happening or where you are running that code) objectively. Your codesniffer is warning you that something outside of a resource model is interacting directly with the database (`join()`), implying that direct db interaction is the remit of a resource model

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
/* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $totalsales */
$totalsales = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['complete']);
$totalsales->getSelect()->join(['item' => 'sales_order_item'], 'main_table.entity_id = item.item_id');
```

Now check your query

```
echo $totalsales->getSelect()->__toString();exit;
```

Comment: I used this but not working for me. I used Magento 2 core model (`Magento\Customer\Model\Customer`).